# Possible to change progress output interval in ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg

Example output:

```
frame= 1234 fps= 25 q= 0.0 size= 10321 time = 00:02:12:31 bitrate= 301.1kbits/s speed=7.21x
```

This output is updated around 4-5 times per second in the terminal.

Is it possible to to change the interval for this status update? Like once per second or once every 10 seconds.

Reason being better overview when queueing several ffmpeg-jobs in a row.
Searched for 'interval' in the documentation but didn't find anything relevant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set `-stats_period 10` to have a 10-second update interval. Available since version 4.4. Default is 0.5 seconds.

Comment: Thank you! Time to update my version soon then.